# jython use urllib2 to make a request throw General SSLEngine

Tags: python, ssl, urllib2, jython

I'm trying to use jython to make a AJAX call. This server will need a 'session.id' to be authorized.

```
url = 'https://somewebsite.com:8443/executor?pa=p1&pb=p2&session.id=ac8884bc-33f2-46e9-9893-5c7b92de5d5e'
urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
```

I run this on python, it works fine.
But when I run it on jython, it throw exceptions. The traceback stack is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/zsun/jython2.7.0/Lib/urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/Users/zsun/jython2.7.0/Lib/urllib2.py", line 404, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/Users/zsun/jython2.7.0/Lib/urllib2.py", line 421, in _open
    result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +
  File "/Users/zsun/jython2.7.0/Lib/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/Users/zsun/jython2.7.0/Lib/urllib2.py", line 1222, in https_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPSConnection, req)
  File "/Users/zsun/jython2.7.0/Lib/urllib2.py", line 1184, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 1] General SSLEngine problem (javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem)>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

More than likely you are dealing with an unsigned certificate.

Since Java *always* checks certificates by default, even if you use the verify=True parameter on the request, look at this to find a Jython-only solution:

http://tech.pedersen-live.com/2010/10/trusting-all-certificates-in-jython/